# what is the meaning of "#$e" in ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.1

I have one string which is contain char like "Pi#$e77L09!($".

But when i tried to print on Console its prints like "Pi!($"

`2.1.2 :002 > str = "Pi#$e77L09!($" => "Pi!($"`

`2.1.2 :003 > puts str Pi!($ => nil`

Answer (score 5):

The magic is in `#`. As you know `"#{ ruby code }"` executes the code in the block and prints it. Similarly, # allows you to access global variables of a program by putting a hash in front of it like so `"#$a"`.

so if you try this code.

```rb
$a = 'test'
puts "#$a"
```

you will see that it prints test. So in your case since `$e77L09` is a non-existent global variable it prints nothing.

if you want to print that string as a string you will need to print it in single quotes. 'Pi#$e77L09!($'

The above usage of "#$1 #$2" is really useful when you use regex. When a string has multiple matching regex it becomes accessible using $1, $2, $3, etc. This stuff came from the Perl world I believe (I am not 100% sure about its history).

EDIT: Like Global Variable supports class and instance variables can be accessed as well.

Comment: @Stefan thanks for that info, have updated the answer. I have used it a lot with regex but never realized doing the same with instance and class variables.

Comment: str = 'Pi#$e77L09!($'
 => "Pi\#$e77L09!($"

Comment: I tried with the single quotes but ists print backslash in that string @coderhs

Comment: @VishuKolekar you want the backslash or don't want it? basically, when you store that single-quoted string to a variable it puts the backslash to denote its not a special character. When you print it using puts you will see that its not showing the `'` . When you convert the str chars using `str.chars`. you can see that there is backslash. `\#` is extracted a single character.

Comment: @coderhs Acutely it is user entered value.. In database its save with the back slash so getting problem with authentication ...

Answer (score 0):

try
puts 'Pi#$e77L09!($'

'#' is the special character which uses for interpolation of string in ruby.

if you use 'Pi#$e77L09!($' it will add \ String Literals before the '#'